# HTC Thunderbolt Killing the home app?

Tags: home-screen, htc-thunderbolt

Something that has been extremely aggravating me recently is that my HTC Thunderbolt seems to be automatically killing the home app whenever it needs space in it's ram.

I notice that this happens when I do something processor intensive like downloading a new app. When I press the home button, it will just display a white screen that says "HTC" on it, and then go to the home and open up a toast saying "loading" just like when the phone first boots up.

At first, I thought it was some of my other apps that were causing it, such as "advanced task killer" and "juice defender ultimate", but I uninstalled Advanced Task Killer, and disabled Juice Defender, and it is still happening.

**Is there a way to stop this?**

Answer (score 1):

If your home screen is dying like this, check your debug logs (if you have adb installed). My guess? You're running out of RAM and Android is killing the home screen process to get more RAM.

You might want to stop some services (or root & remove stupid carrier bloatware).

CyanogenMOD and some other custom Android builds will allow you to "lock" the application in RAM, but honestly that can cause as many problems as it solves.

On my older phones (HTC Dream / HTC Magic) the culprit at the time was K-9 mail.